# TLS-PSK support in cURL

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl

I need to create a libcurl application to download url from https server (Authentication mechanism is PSK).
So I just downloaded the TLS-PSK supported cURL code from the below link.
https://github.com/curl/curl/tree/d2f8bbf2600d5da577ab75a4fd7ba3e129aba4be
(As per my understanding the currently published cURL doesn't have support for the TLS-PSK. Correct me if I am wrong.)

But on executing my sample application it shows ssl error: "sslv3 alert bad record mac".

Actually I am new to this and I don't have much knowledge on TLS/SSL and also curl.
It will be really helpful if anyone could provide a solution for this.

Below I have also attached the src code, log and test results from my behalf for reference.

Samplecurl.cpp

```
int main()
{
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://localhost:1440/");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_PSK, "client_id:fcc56e7668194a4775e5b36e2735551a");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Step 1: started server using openssl command (openssl version is- OpenSSL 1.0.2g)

```
openssl s_server -psk fcc56e7668194a4775e5b36e2735551a -accept 1440 -cipher PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA -nocert
```

Step 2: Build the Samplecurl.cpp with the downloaded source code and got the following error

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 1440 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac
* Closing connection 0
curl_easy_perform() failed: SSL connect error
```

*** With curl command line also the same error occurred.

curl-command:

curl -v --tls-psk Client_identity:fcc56e7668194a4775e5b36e2735551a -k https://localhost:1440/ --ciphers PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 1440 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac
```

Please note that using openssl client command, connection to the server was success. Command is given below.

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:1440 -psk fcc56e7668194a4775e5b36e2735551a
```

On executing the above command, the terminal shows the following

```
>> CONNECTED(00000003)

>> no peer certificate available

>> No client certificate CA names sent

>> SSL handshake has read 338 bytes and written 414 bytes

>> New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
>> Secure Renegotiation IS supported
>> Compression: NONE
>> Expansion: NONE
>> No ALPN negotiated
>> SSL-Session:
    >> Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    >> Cipher    : PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
    >> Session-ID: AC3096F9E9AAC227B4FE4DFD59CBD3B9A2EA230B22A83289323EF5F2F8C7DAE5
    >> Session-ID-ctx: 
    >> Master-Key: 07314810B7A54B94EA9F8497736F383733290EB5BFC64A557D0B3A780F518FC9CF55BFC408C5361B91D92A1B4786E314
    >> Key-Arg   : None
    >> PSK identity: Client_identity
    >> PSK identity hint: None
    >> SRP username: None
    >> TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    >> TLS session ticket:
    0000 - b4 92 80 4f ec 7b f2 17-c3 59 03 6f 62 63 62 5b   ...O.{...Y.obcb[
    0010 - 30 d4 d4 9d 5f 5f 07 df-8f 7d 4f f8 98 fa af 41   0...__...}O....A
    0020 - 2a 11 53 1a c4 16 86 f1-24 38 b7 bf 9c 1c 7d 5a   *.S.....$8....}Z
    0030 - e3 bd 94 b4 01 e1 a7 75-95 b0 a1 c5 be 71 51 45   .......u.....qQE
    0040 - 74 0b cb 7a a5 b8 ac 42-64 dc 06 c5 23 23 de 33   t..z...Bd...##.3
    0050 - 0e 94 87 cc ed 65 f1 e4-da bc 4f 5e 3d e9 46 96   .....e....O^=.F.
    0060 - ae 0e 4c d4 98 2e 01 9d-e3 6e 54 f2 c2 08 13 a9   ..L......nT.....
    0070 - 1a 33 46 08 90 12 17 5b-e5 62 ca 23 24 93 97 1c   .3F....[.b.#$...
    0080 - 39 70 a6 4d 2c 12 6e 9c-53 e7 08 b5 ad 90 02 0d   9p.M,.n.S.......
    0090 - 6c e8 ef e3 9b 76 f5 2a-ae 64 47 b5 84 a0 08 26   l....v.*.dG....&
    00a0 - ec 1f 32 1c 5d 25 9e d0-cf c5 a2 8d 6b 2e de e1   ..2.]%......k...
Start Time: 1528369235
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Comment: That curl patch you link to is 3 years old so I would be very wary about using it. It also looks limited in that, AFAICT, the CURLOPT_SSL _PSK option expects you to provide the *actual* (binary) key...not a hex representation of the key. Which tends to limit its use to keys that contain exclusively printable characters in the key...a significant limitation which would make even more wary about using this. This is most likely the reason why it is failing for you (when you do the openssl s_server test, the s_server -psk option will convert the hex into an actual binary key)

Comment: Yeah, that seems mostly like a libcurl bug...

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I found something. Running openssl s_server command with psk-key in ascii format solved the bad mac error.
openssl s_server -psk 666163646566 -accept 1440 -cipher PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA -nocert

Client Side - With CURLOPT_SSL_PSK
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_PSK, "Client_identity:facdef");

Comment: The link of the patch is dead. As of version 7.88 (currently the latest version) , it is still not possible to fetch pre-shared key from previous `curl` command and then reuse the same key for next `curl` command.